# Problema con Neatbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

No se si sea una pregunta que se debe hacer aqui ya que no tiene que ver con codigo directamente pero como tiene que ver con el entorno me parece un buen lugar para preguntar. Reciente baje NetBeans 8.2 de la pagina oficial.. Como tambien trabajo con C++ asi que me baje la vercion ALL que pesa 221 MB. Para tener todo alli por si acaso, tambien instale la JDK 8u181 y la JRE 8u181. Configure tambien las dos variables de sitema JAVA_HOME y JRE_HOME (segun la pagina ambas tenian que tener el mismo diretorio de JDK). El problema viene cuando abro NetBeans, no deja hacer NADA, absolutamente NADA, me deja clickear las opciones de arriba y luego se cuelga y tengo que cerrarlo por administrador, abajo me di cuenta que sale un globito de dialogo con un numero dos que por un momente dice UNEXPECTE EXEPCION, osea todo lo que clickee se queda colgado el programa

nota* al instalarlo solo selecciones los componentes de Java SE y C/C++, al principio pense que era por instalarlo todo pero luego lo reinstale asi y siguio igual.

Comment: Puede ser debido a restos de una vieja instalación que no se desinstaló correctamente. Prueba a desinstalar Netbeans por la vía correcta. Reinicia, revisa que no haya restos en carpetas e instala de nuevo el paquete correcto según tu sistema operativo.

Comment: Imposible, es la primera vez que voy a trabajar con java, lo unico que tenia instalado antes era en JRE, y todo eso lo he hecho ya cientos de veces, desinstalar el JRE, JDK incluso instale el Net con solo c++ y es peor aun

Comment: En el sitio oficial de Oracle NetBeans hay un enlace para descargar un Bundle que incluye todo **suele ser el medio idoneo** para instalar de modo que funcione correctamente. La dirección es: [JDK with NetBeans IDE Java SE bundle.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html) Yo lo he instalado desde allí muchas veces, **sin fallos** . Y me ha fallado como a tí cuando descargo el paquete usual.

Comment: No especificaste el Sistema Operativo, suponiendo que es Windows, Intenta desinstalar netbeans, luego elimina manualmente, si existe, el directorio creado en Program Files\Netbeans (o el que usaste para instalar). Luego borra los directorios de datos del usuario. C:\Users\Tu_Usuario\AppData\Local\Netbeans y también C:\Users\Tu_Usuario\AppData\Roaming\Netbeans. Finalmente pasa un limpiador, como ccleaner, para que borre datos temporales. Reintentar la instalación a ver cómo resulta ahora.

Comment: Olvidé anotar: Las instrucciones de instalación, para todos los SO soportados se encuentran en [Instalation intructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/install-jdk6-22nb691-177131.html) y funciona perfectamente. Tengo instalaciones en Win, Linux y Mac sin problemas

Comment: @quevedo muchas gracias amigo tu respuesta fue la correcta, ni idea que estaba ese link, con ese paquete si funciona, estaba usando eclipse hasta hora pero me parecia un poco lento (para mi pc) netbeans ahora si anda perfecto

Comment: Aunque ya solucionaste tu problema, ¿tienes alguna otra versión del JDK instalado además de la versión que específicaste?

Comment: no como habia dicho era la primera vez que lo instalo y por lo tanto descargue solo los componentes mas nuevos